# Can I compile with a library without dso problems?

Tags: c++, unix, reference, shared-libraries

I need some help about library compilation.

It is possible to create a library linked with -lsfml-audio for example and use this generated library without l-sfml-audio flag ?

Because if I don't put this during compilation:
`-lmylib -lsfml-audio` and only `-lmylib`
it failed and return undefined symbol with DSO is missing.

If it's possible to do it I want to know it please.

Thanks in advance. Antoine.

Comment: Do you use `-lsfml-audio` when linking `mylib`?

Comment: I suggest you add details, something like: _I created a shared library liba.so that is linked with libb.so, then tried to use my library to create an executable c : `cc c.o -la`. This failed with the error `undefined symbol sym1 in c.o`. In this environment the library libb.so is not available_

Comment: If the undefined symbol error is from the new code that you compiled and the sfml-audio library is not available in your build environment, you can't link like this.